# Multi-factor Voice Authentication

Tags: authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication, voice-recognition

Was wondering if one could set up Multi-factor Voice Authentication along with traditional OTP based 2FA for logging in to their GNU/Linux, and superuser escalations. There are some posts from about a decade back on askubuntu which say it's not. perhaps things have changed since then... So, has anyone out here set something like this up? How do I go about it if I want to set it up.

TIA!

Comment: Multi-factor Authentication: yes. 2FA: yes. Multi-factor Voice Authentication: not that I know of but I would assume this is up to the authenticator you use on your phone for this and not about Ubuntu. All Ubuntu needs is an access code sent from the phone. That is not going to be an audio segment.

Comment: @Rinzwind when you say yes for MFA, what other ways are available currently, other than OTP-based solutions?

Comment: eh I don't get that question: 2FA is always OTP. 2FA does 2 OTPs. In case of the google auth. you would use a QR and your password.

Comment: 2FA has become synonymous with OTP: using libpam-google-authenticator with Google auth/autho, etc, on your phone; YES. That doesn't mean 2FA HAS to always be OTP. Perhaps, to rephrase my question; I wanted to know if you were acquainted with any other way to use Multi-factor auth on Linux other than OTP based 2FA.

Comment: Ah. Then no. The way 2fa works seems sufficient: 1 is something you know and the 2nd is something that you own (ie. password you know + phone you have). I doubt anything else is going to make is more secure with the same level of difficulty to access a machine